# How to join tables based on the dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

`COMMISSION` table

```
PRODUCT_ID   DATE       COMMISSION
1           20110101       27.00     
1           20120101       28.00
1           20130705       30.00
2           20110101       17.00
2           20120501       16.00
2           20130101       18.00
...
```

`ORDER` table

```
PRODUCT_ID   DATE        PRICE
1            20110405      2500
2            20130402      3000 
2            20130101      1900
```

Desired output

```
PRODUCT_ID      DATE      PRICE       COMMISSION
1             20110405    2500         27.00
2             20130402    3000         16.00
2             20130101    1900         18.00
```

- `Commission` table records commission % based on the product id and date.
- `Order` table is basically a record of orders placed on a particular date,

I'd like to join two tables and bring the appropriate commission based on the date of the order. For example, you can see that the first order's commission is 27.00 as the date for the product_id 1 falls between 20110101 and 20120101.

How do I do this? Seems like a simple 1 to n relationship but I can't figure it out.

Comment: is there typos in the desired result dates?

Comment: I believe in your desired output the commission for product_id `2` on `20130402`  should be `18.00` instead of `16.00`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT o.*,
(
  SELECT TOP 1 commission
    FROM commission
   WHERE product_id = o.product_id
     AND date <= o.date
   ORDER BY date DESC
) commission
  FROM [order] o
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/102bc/1)** demo